# Regressões lineares em DIC com parcela subdividida

Tags: r, regressão, lattice

Olá, boa tarde!

gostarias de saber, como realizar uma regressão linear em dic com parcela subdividida, detalhe eu preciso dos "betas", pois pretendo utilizar a resposta para predizer uma curva!

dados de exemplo:

```
dados<-structure(list(Fator1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("AV1", "AV2", "AV3"), class = "factor"), Fator2 = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L), REP = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), resposta = c(1.7, 
1.8, 1.7, 1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 1.5, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.6, 
1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.7, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 
1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.7, 
1.5, 1.6, 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 1.7, 
1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.8, 1.8, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.8, 1.9, 1.9, 1.6, 
1.8, 1.5, 1.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 
1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.2, 1.5, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.4, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 
1.6, 1.8)), .Names = c("Fator1", "Fator2", "REP", "resposta"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
120L))
```

Eu já vi um modelo porém em DBC:

```
m1<-aov(resposta~bloco+Fator1+Error(bloco:Fator1)+Fator2+Fator1:Fator2, data=dados)
```

não consegui chegar a mesma resposta para DIC, apenas substituindo os blocos pela repetição, e ou retirando o bloco do código.

Eu utilizei para comparar a resposta, o resultado apresentando pelo pacote ExpDes.pt::psub.dic

preciso dos "betas" pois pretendo utilizar o comando para predição

```
predicao<-expand.grid(Fator1,Fator2)
predicao<-cbind(predicao, predict(m1, newdata=predicao, interval="confidence")
```

para fazer aquela faixa 95% da curva.

Answer (score 3):

A primeira coisa a se fazer quando vamos analisar um experimento é a análise exploratória dos dados. Não ficou explícito na tua pergunta, mas estou assumindo que o Fator1 diz respeito às parcelas e o Fator2, às subparcelas.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=Fator2, y=resposta)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~ Fator1)
```

[image: split plot]

Este gráfico já nos dá uma ideia do que esperar dos resultados dos nossos testes. Como não conheço o pacote `ExpDes.pt`, optei por realizar a análise utilizando o comando `aov`, nativo do `R`.

```
modelo <- aov(resposta ~ Fator1*Fator2 + Error(REP:Fator1), data=dados)
summary(modelo)

Error: REP:Fator1
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Fator1     2 0.7300  0.3650   31.54  0.125
Residuals  1 0.0116  0.0116               

Error: Within
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Fator1          2 0.0905 0.04523   2.598 0.07894 . 
Fator2          1 0.1707 0.17067   9.804 0.00223 **
Fator1:Fator2   2 0.0646 0.03229   1.855 0.16128   
Residuals     111 1.9324 0.01741                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Eu ajustei um modelo com dois efeitos principais e interação entre eles, por isso a fórmula `Fator1*Fator2`. Além disso, disse que o termo com erro depende da repetição dentro do `Fator1`; por isso, coloquei `Error(REP:Fator1)`.

Note que o termo de interação não foi significante ao nível de 5%. Por isso, vou ajustar um novo modelo, sem a parte de interação:

```
modelo.reduzido <- aov(resposta ~ Fator1+Fator2 + Error(REP:Fator1), data=dados)
summary(modelo.reduzido)

Error: REP:Fator1
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Fator1     2 0.7300  0.3650   31.54  0.125
Residuals  1 0.0116  0.0116               

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Fator1      2 0.0905 0.04523   2.559 0.08184 . 
Fator2      1 0.1707 0.17067   9.657 0.00239 **
Residuals 113 1.9970 0.01767                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Apenas o Fator2 foi significante ao nível de 5%.

Para verificar se as hipóteses do modelo foram satisfeitas, rodamos o código baixo:

```
modelo.plot <- aov(resposta ~ Fator1+Fator2 + REP:Fator1, data=dados)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(modelo.plot)
```

[image: residuos]

Perceba que ajustei um novo modelo, sem `Error`, por causa de uma limitação 
do `R`. Se tu rodar `summary(modelo.plot)` vai ver que as inferências estão diferentes, mas não te preocupa. O que interessa aqui são os resíduos.

Resíduos que, por sinal, estão esquisitos. Parece que há um padrão nos gráficos dos resíduos versus valores ajustados e scale-location. Parece que falta aleatoriedade nestes dados. Eu investigaria isto mais a fundo para saber de onde eles vieram e porque isto está acontecendo.

O QQ-Plot indica resíduos normalmente distribuídos e, de acordo com a leverage, não há pontos de influência neste conjunto de dados.

Vou ficar devendo a parte da previsão. Eu nunca via algo assim ser feito neste contexto. Pode ser desconhecimento meu, mas procurei algo parecido em alguns livros aqui em casa e não encontrei nada a respeito.

---

Edição feita para expandir meu [comentário anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158668/regress%C3%B5es-lineares-em-dic-com-parcela-subdividida#comment327592_158744):

As hipóteses que testei para as subparcelas em meu código acima foi

H_0: a inclinação nas retas das subparcelas é igual
H_1: há pelo menos um par de inclinações nas retas das subparcelas que é diferente

Eu pensei melhor sobre o problema e estou achando que estas hipóteses não fazem sentido. Veja o primeiro gráfico que desenhei. A inclinação das respostas dentro de AV1 e AV2 me parecem ser diferentes de zero, enquanto a reta dentro de AV3 me parece ter inclinação igual a zero.

E agora vem uma parte importante, que não depende de contas.

Vamos pensar um pouco. Será mesmo que podemos utilizar apenas 5 pontos para determinar se há uma relação entre uma variável preditora e uma variável resposta? Veja, no primeiro gráfico, como os pontos não se organizam muito bem numa reta dentro de AV1 e AV2. Veja como eles estão muito mal organizados em formato de reta.

O caso das respostas em AV3 é ainda pior. Ali temos um comportamento linear, como o de AV1 ou AV2, com uma reta? Ou é uma reta com inclinação zero? Ou é uma parábola? Ou uma cúbica? Matematicamente, tendo 5 pontos para a variável preditora, podemos ajustar até um polinômio de quarta ordem.

Mas isto faz sentido? Eu, pensando melhor no assunto, acho que não. Inclusive, estou achando que ajustar uma reta a estes dados não é uma boa ideia, e abaixo comento isto melhor.

Entretanto, o teste de hipóteses que fiz reporta que há uma diferença em nas inclinações de um par destas retas. Não fiz os testes de comparações posteriores, mas imagino que as retas dentro de AV1 e AV2 tenham inclinações semelhantes e a reta de AV3 tenha inclinação igual a zero. Não vejo sentido em testar polinômios de ordem mais alta.

Eu defendo que sempre temos que procurar explicações no mundo real para aquilo que encontramos utilizando a estatística. Depois de rodarmos os testes, é fundamental explicarmos o que estamos vendo neste monte de números. O teu problema, depois da tua explicação de ontem, ficou claro para mim. Me parece fazer sentido dizer que, se a dose de Adubação Orgânica (`Fator2`) aumenta, o Diâmetro (`resposta`) pode aumentar para duas épocas de avaliação (`Fator1`, níveis `AV1` e `AV2`) ou não aumentar (`Fator1`, níveis `AV3`). Só saberemos isto de fato se fizermos os testes post-hoc.

Ainda assim, creio que assumir que há uma relação linear entre as variáveis `resposta` e `Fator2` é uma hipótese muito forte. Na minha opinião, há poucos pontos para que isto possa ser, de fato, assumido. Assim, concordo contigo que deveriam haver 4 graus de liberdade para `Fator2`. Porém, assim perderemos o poder de previsão que uma regressão poderia nos dar neste caso. O código, portanto, ficaria

```
modelo.completo <- aov(resposta ~ Fator1*as.factor(Fator2) + 
    Error(as.factor(REP)/Fator1), data=dados)
summary(modelo.completo)

Error: as.factor(REP)
          Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  7 0.03967 0.005667               

Error: as.factor(REP):Fator1
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Fator1     2 0.7952  0.3976    91.5 9.16e-09 ***
Residuals 14 0.0608  0.0043                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
                         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
as.factor(Fator2)         4 0.5263 0.13158  10.359 7.22e-07 ***
Fator1:as.factor(Fator2)  8 0.5107 0.06383   5.025 4.10e-05 ***
Residuals                84 1.0670 0.01270                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Perceba que, ao contrário do meu código original, desta vez tomei o cuidado necessário para transformar em fatores aqueles termos que estavam como números.

Note que, agora, temos uma interação significativa entre `Fator1` e `Fator2`. Ou seja, Época de Avaliação e Adubação Orgânica interagem entre si. Não sei o que significa Época de Avaliação, mas tem algo a ver com a estação do ano?

Veja que os resíduos continuam um pouco esquisitos:

[image: resíduos 2]

Comparando os resultados do meu modelo com o teu, eles estão muito mais parecidos. Ainda são diferentes quantitativamente, mas são erros de arredondamento. Aparentemente, depois da minha revisão, chegamos ao mesmo resultado.

Mas este resultado não serve para fazer a previsão que tu deseja. Ele serve para fazer os testes pos-hoc, para comparar as médias entre as subparcelas, mas não podemos fazer previsão. Inclusive, como relatei acima, acho incorreto que façamos previsão neste caso, pois temos muitos poucos dados para estabelecer um critério de relação entre Diâmetro e Adubação Orgânica. Fazer uma comparação entre as médias obtidas para Adubação Orgânica me parece muito mais adequado.

Comment: Os graus de liberdade para o `Fator2` seria 4, e no caso o seu modelo, foi apresentado 1.

Comment: Discordo. Seriam 4 graus de liberdade se a variável `Fator2` fosse qualitativa. No teu problema, ela é considerada quantitativa. Portanto, é um grau de liberdade apenas. Compare, por exemplo, com um modelo de regressão, tipo estes dois: `x <- 1:10; y <- x+rnorm(10); anova(lm(y ~ x))` e `x <- 1:100; y <- x+rnorm(100); anova(lm(y ~ x))`. Note que a variável preditora em cada um dos casos é `x`. No primeiro caso, ela tem tamanho 10. No segundo, 100. Em ambos os casos, a tabela ANOVA atribui apenas um grau de liberdade a `x`, porque ela não é qualitativa.

Comment: Trabalhei um pouco mais na minha resposta. Dê uma olhada nela.